# Boost.Python create new reference to existing Python object from C++

Tags: python, c++, initialization, boost-python

I am wrapping a C++ class `X` using Boost.Python. At the moment an object of this class is created, I would like to insert an additional reference to this object into the local namespace (so that I can refer to his newly created object by a fixed name, let's say `lastX`). I tried
to do this in the `X::X()` constructor using

```
X::X() 
   {
   boost::python::object locals(boost::python::borrowed(PyEval_GetLocals()));
   boost::python::object me(this);
   locals["lastX"]=me;
   }
```

but this does not work (`lastX` gets created but it refers to nothing; printing it from Python leads to a segfault). I should probably use my own `init` function but I do not know how to get a reference to the newly created Python object there either.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Needing this type of feature may be an indication of code smell, and worth the time to seek out alternative solutions, such as patching initializers to store weak references into a well defined registrar, rather than modifying the caller's locals.

Answer (score 4):

To accomplish this, one must modify another frame on the call stack.  Be warned, this is dependent on the Python implementation. For example, in Python 2.7, the [`inspect`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html) module and [`sys.settrace()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.settrace) can be used to modify [`locals()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#locals) on a specific frame.

I would highly recommend using a Python solution, as was done in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21976146/1053968) answer, and monkey patch the desired class' `__init__` function.  For instance, the following would patch the `Spam` class to insert a variable named `last_spam` that references the newly constructed `Spam` instance into the caller's frame:

```python
def _patch_init(cls, name):
    cls_init = getattr(cls, '__init__', None)
    def patch(self):
        caller_frame = inspect.currentframe(1)
        new_locals = caller_frame.f_locals
        new_locals[name] = self
        _force_locals(caller_frame, new_locals)
        if cls_init:
            cls_init(self)
    setattr(cls, '__init__', patch)

_patch_init(Spam, 'last_spam')

spam = Spam()
assert(spam is last_spam)
```

---

Nevertheless, the same can be accomplished with Boost.Python.  To accomplish this, one must:

- Modify a frame's `locals()`.
- Access the `self` instance during object construction.

Be warned, these can be fairly advance topics.

### Modify a frame's `locals()`

This is the same approach used in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21976146/1053968) answer, which is dependent on the Python implementation, but written in C++.  In most execution paths, a frame's `locals()` cannot have new variables written into it.  However, when system tracing is enabled, frame tracing functions, often used by debuggers and other tools, can modify a frame's `locals()`.

```cpp
/// @brief Trace signature type.  Boost.Python requires MPL signature for
///        custom functors.
typedef boost::mpl::vector<
  boost::python::object, // return
  boost::python::object, // frame
  boost::python::object, // event
  boost::python::object // argt
> trace_signature_type;

/// @brief A noop function for Python.  Returns None.
boost::python::object noop(
  boost::python::tuple /* args */,
  boost::python::dict /* kw */
)
{
  return boost::python::object();
}

/// @brief Inject new_locals into the provided frame.
void inject_locals_into_frame(
  boost::python::object frame,
  boost::python::dict new_locals
)
{
  namespace python = boost::python;
  // Force tracing by setting the global tracing function to any non-None
  // function.
  // # if not sys.gettrace():
  if (!PyThreadState_Get()->c_tracefunc)
  {
    // Use the sys.settrace function to prevent needing to re-implement the
    // trace trampoline.
    //   # import sys
    python::object sys(python::handle<>(PyImport_ImportModule("sys")));
    //   # sys.settrace(lambda *args, **keys: None)
    sys.attr("__dict__")["settrace"](python::raw_function(&detail::noop));
  }

  // Create trace function.
  //   # def trace(frame, event, arg):
  python::object trace = python::make_function([new_locals](
        python::object frame,
        python::object /* event */,
        python::object /* arg */
      )
      {
        // Update the frame's locals.
        //   # frame.f_locals.update(new_locals)
        frame.attr("f_locals").attr("update")(new_locals);

        // Set the frame to use default trace, preventing this
        // trace functor from resetting the locals on each trace call.
        //   # del frame.f_trace
        frame.attr("f_trace").del();

        //   # return None
        return boost::python::object();
      },
    python::default_call_policies(),
    trace_signature_type());

  // Set the frame to use the custom trace.
  //   # frame.f_trace = trace
  frame.attr("f_trace") = trace;
}
```

With the above code, one can use `inject_into_frame_locals()` to update a given frame's locals.  For example, the following will add a variable `x` that references `42` into the current frame:

```cpp
// Create dictionary that will be injected into the current frame.
namespace python = boost::python;
python::dict new_locals;
new_locals["x"] = 42;

// Get a handle to the current frame.
python::object frame(python::borrowed(
  reinterpret_cast<PyObject*>(PyEval_GetFrame())));

// Set locals to be injected into the frame.
inject_into_frame_locals(frame, new_locals);
```

---

### Access the `self` instance during object construction.

Given a C++ object, one cannot use the Boost.Python API to locate the Python object in which the object is held.  Thus, one must access `self` as Boost.Python is constructing the object.

There are a few customization points:

- Modify the class being exposed to accept `PyObject*` during construction.  One can have Boost.Python provide the `PyObject*` instance be specializing [`has_back_reference`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/python/doc/v2/has_back_reference.html):

  ```cpp
  struct foo
  {
    // Constructor.
    foo(PyObject* self)
    {
      namespace python = boost::python;
      python::handle<> handle(python::borrowed(self));
      trace::inject_into_current_frame("last_foo", python::object(handle));
    }

    // Boost.Python copy constructor.
    foo(PyObject* self, const foo& /* rhs */)
    {
      namespace python = boost::python;
      python::handle<> handle(python::borrowed(self));
      trace::inject_into_current_frame("last_foo", python::object(handle));
    }
  };

  namespace boost {
  namespace python {
    // Have Boost.Python pass PyObject self to foo during construction.
    template <>
    struct has_back_reference<foo>
      : boost::mpl::true_
    {};
  } // namespace python
  } // namespace boost

  BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(example)
  {
    namespace python = boost::python;
    python::class_<foo>("Foo", python::init<>());
  }
  ```
- Expose the `T` as being held by a [`HeldType`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/python/doc/v2/class.html#HeldType) that derives from `T`.  When the `HeldType` is publicly derived from the `T`, it will be provided `PyObject*` during construction:

  ```cpp
  struct bar {};

  struct bar_holder
    : public bar
  {
    bar_holder(PyObject* self)
    {
     namespace python = boost::python;
      python::handle<> handle(python::borrowed(self));
      trace::inject_into_current_frame("last_bar", python::object(handle));
    }

    bar_holder(PyObject* self, const bar& /* rhs */)
    {
      namespace python = boost::python;
      python::handle<> handle(python::borrowed(self));
      trace::inject_into_current_frame("last_bar", python::object(handle));
   }
  };

  BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(example)
  {
    namespace python = boost::python;
    python::class_<bar, bar_holder>("Bar", python::init<>());
  }
  ```
- Suppress Boost.Python from generating a default initializer with [`boost::python::no_init`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/python/doc/v2/class.html#class_-spec-ctors), then register a custom factory function as the `__init__` method with custom policies.  One key function for customizing object construction is the [`boost::python::make_constructor`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/python/doc/v2/make_function.html#make_constructor-spec) function.  When provided a pointer to a C++ function or pointer-to-member-function, it will return a Python callable object, which when called, will invoke the function and create the Python object.  However, Boost.Python attempts to hide Python-specific details from the C++ functions, and thus `self` is not explicitly provided.  Nevertheless, one can use a a custom [CallPolicy](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/python/doc/v2/CallPolicies.html#CallPolicies-concept), and access the Python arguments within either the `precall` or `postcall` functions.  In order to access the `self` argument, one has to be aware of an implementation detail with `make_constructor`'s policies, which offsets argument access by 1.  For instance, when attempting to access the `self` argument that resides at index `0`, one must request the `-1` index.

  ```cpp
  // Mockup models.
  class spam {};

  // Factor functions for the models will be necessary, as custom constructor
  // functions will be needed to provide a customization hook for our models.
  spam* make_spam() { return new spam(); }

  template <typename BasePolicy = boost::python::default_call_policies>
  struct custom_policy
    : BasePolicy
  {     
    template <typename ArgumentPackage>
    PyObject* postcall(const ArgumentPackage& args, PyObject* result)
    {
      namespace python = boost::python;

      // Chain to base policy.
      result = BasePolicy::postcall(args, result);

      // self is the first argument.  It is an implementation detail that
      // the make_constructor policy will offset access by 1.  Thus, to 
      // access the actual object at index 0 (self), one must use -1.
      python::object self(python::borrowed(
        get(boost::mpl::int_<-1>(), args)));

      return result;
    }
  };

  BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(example)
  {
    namespace python = boost::python;
    python::class_<spam>("Spam", python::no_init)
      .def("__init__", python::make_constructor(
        &make_spam, 
        custom_policy<>()))
     ;
  }
  ```
- Once again, the default initializer can be suppressed and the object returned by `make_constructor` can be decorated.  When the `__init__` method is invoked, the decorator object will be invoked where it will be provided all the arguments for the initializer, including `self`.  The decorator will need to delegate to the object returned from `make_constructor`.  Use [`boost::python::make_function()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/python/doc/v2/make_function.html#make_function-spec) to transform a C++ functor to a callable Python object.  Please note that the `make_function` documentation does not state it supports custom functors.  However, it is used internally for functor support.

  ```cpp
  // Mockup models.
  class egg {};

  // Factor functions for the models will be necessary, as custom constructor
  // functions will be needed to provide a customization hook for our models.
  egg* make_egg() { return new egg(); }

  template <typename Fn>
  class custom_constructor
  {
  public:

    typedef boost::python::object result_type;

  public:

    custom_constructor(Fn fn)
      : constructor_(boost::python::make_constructor(fn))
    {}

    /// @brief Initialize python object.
    template <typename ...Args>
    result_type operator()(boost::python::object self, Args... args)
    {
      return constructor_(self, args...);
    }

  private:
    boost::python::object constructor_;
  };

  template <typename Fn>
  boost::python::object make_custom_constructor(Fn fn)
  {
    // Use MPL to decompose the factory function signature into the
    // desired Python object signature.
    typedef /* ... */ signature_type;

    // Create a callable python object from custom_constructor.
    return boost::python::make_function(
      custom_constructor<Fn>(fn),
      boost::python::default_call_policies(),
      signature_type());
  }

  BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(example)
  {
    namespace python = boost::python;
    python::class_<egg>("Egg", python::no_init)
      .def("__init__", make_custom_constructor(&make_egg))
      ;
  }
  ```

---

Here is a complete example [demonstrating](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7553e1acbacf84ce) all of the above approaches:

```cpp
#include <boost/function_types/components.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/insert_range.hpp>
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <boost/python/raw_function.hpp>

namespace trace {
namespace detail {

/// @brief Trace signature type.  Boost.Python requires MPL signature for
///        custom functors.
typedef boost::mpl::vector<
  boost::python::object, // return
  boost::python::object, // frame
  boost::python::object, // event
  boost::python::object  // arg
> trace_signature_type;

/// @brief A noop function for Python.  Returns None.
boost::python::object noop(
  boost::python::tuple /* args */,
  boost::python::dict /* kw */
)
{
  return boost::python::object();
}

} // namespace detail

/// @brief Inject new_locals into the provided frame.
void inject_into_frame_locals(
  boost::python::object frame,
  boost::python::dict new_locals
)
{
  namespace python = boost::python;
  // Force tracing by setting the global tracing function to any non-None
  // function.
  // # if not sys.gettrace():
  if (!PyThreadState_Get()->c_tracefunc)
  {
    // Use the sys.settrace function to prevent needing to re-implement the
    // trace trampoline.
    //   # import sys
    python::object sys(python::handle<>(PyImport_ImportModule("sys")));
    //   # sys.settrace(lambda *args, **keys: None)
    sys.attr("__dict__")["settrace"](python::raw_function(&detail::noop));
  }

  // Create trace function.
  //   # def trace(frame, event, arg):
  python::object trace = python::make_function([new_locals](
        python::object frame,
        python::object /* event */,
        python::object /* arg */
      )
      {
        // Update the frame's locals.
        //   # frame.f_locals.update(new_locals)
        frame.attr("f_locals").attr("update")(new_locals);

        // Set the frame to use default trace, preventing this
        // trace functor from resetting the locals on each trace call.
        //   # del frame.f_trace
        frame.attr("f_trace").del();

        //   # return None
        return boost::python::object();
      },
    python::default_call_policies(),
    detail::trace_signature_type());

  // Set the frame to use the custom trace.
  //   # frame.f_trace = trace
  frame.attr("f_trace") = trace;
}

/// @brief Helper function used to setup tracing to inject the key-value pair
///        into the current frame.
void inject_into_current_frame(
  std::string key,
  boost::python::object value)
{
  // If there is no key, just return early.
  if (key.empty()) return;

  // Create dictionary that will be injected into the current frame.
  namespace python = boost::python;
  python::dict new_locals;
  new_locals[key] = value;

  // Get a handle to the current frame.
  python::object frame(python::borrowed(
    reinterpret_cast<PyObject*>(PyEval_GetFrame())));

  // Set locals to be injected into the frame.
  inject_into_frame_locals(frame, new_locals);
}

} // namespace trace

/// APPROACH 1: has_back_reference

struct foo
{
  // Constructor.
  foo(PyObject* self)
  {
    namespace python = boost::python;
    python::handle<> handle(python::borrowed(self));
    trace::inject_into_current_frame("last_foo", python::object(handle));
  }

  // Boost.Python copy constructor.
  foo(PyObject* self, const foo& /* rhs */)
  {
    namespace python = boost::python;
    python::handle<> handle(python::borrowed(self));
    trace::inject_into_current_frame("last_foo", python::object(handle));
  }
};

namespace boost {
namespace python {
  // Have Boost.Python pass PyObject self to foo during construction.
  template <>
  struct has_back_reference<foo>
    : boost::mpl::true_
  {};
} // namespace python
} // namespace boost

/// APPROACH 2: custom holder

struct bar {};

struct bar_holder
  : public bar
{
  bar_holder(PyObject* self)
  {
    namespace python = boost::python;
    python::handle<> handle(python::borrowed(self));
    trace::inject_into_current_frame("last_bar", python::object(handle));
  }

  bar_holder(PyObject* self, const bar& /* rhs */)
  {
    namespace python = boost::python;
    python::handle<> handle(python::borrowed(self));
    trace::inject_into_current_frame("last_bar", python::object(handle));
  }
};

/// APPROACH 3: custom call policy

struct spam {};

/// @brief CallPolicy that injects a reference to the returned object
///        into the caller's frame.  Expected to only be used as a
//         policy for make_constructor.
template <typename BasePolicy = boost::python::default_call_policies>
struct inject_reference_into_callers_frame
  : BasePolicy
{
  inject_reference_into_callers_frame(const char* name)
    : name_(name)
  {}

  template <typename ArgumentPackage>
  PyObject* postcall(const ArgumentPackage& args, PyObject* result)
  {
    // Chain to base policy.
    result = BasePolicy::postcall(args, result);

    // self is the first argument.  It is an implementation detail that
    // the make_constructor policy will offset access by 1.  Thus, to 
    // access the actual object at index 0 (self), one must use -1.
    namespace python = boost::python;
    python::object self(python::borrowed(
      get(boost::mpl::int_<-1>(), args)));

    // Inject into the current frame. 
    trace::inject_into_current_frame(name_, self);

    return result;
  }

private:
  std::string name_;
};

// Factor functions for the models will be necessary, as custom constructor
// functions will be needed to provide a customization hook for our models.
spam* make_spam() { return new spam(); }

/// APPROACH 4: decorated constructor
//
struct egg {};

namespace detail {

/// @brief A constructor functor that injects the constructed object
///        into the caller's frame.
template <typename Fn>
class inject_constructor
{
public:

  typedef boost::python::object result_type;

public:

  /// @brief Constructor.
  inject_constructor(
    const char* name,
    Fn fn
  )
    : name_(name),
      constructor_(boost::python::make_constructor(fn))
  {}

  /// @brief Initialize the python objet.
  template <typename ...Args>
  result_type operator()(boost::python::object self, Args... args)
  {
    // Initialize the python object.
    boost::python::object result = constructor_(self, args...);

    // Inject a reference to self into the current frame.
    trace::inject_into_current_frame(name_, self);

    return result;
  }

private:
  std::string name_;
  boost::python::object constructor_;
};

} // namespace detail

/// @brief Makes a wrapper constructor (constructor that works with
///        classes inheriting from boost::python::wrapper).
template <typename Fn>
boost::python::object make_inject_constructor(
  const char* name,
  Fn fn)
{
  // Decompose the factory function signature, removing the return type.
  typedef typename boost::mpl::pop_front<
    typename boost::function_types::components<Fn>::type
  >::type components_type;

  // Python constructors take the instance/self argument as the first
  // argument, and returns None.  Thus, inject python::objects into the
  // signature type for both the return and 'self' argument.
  typedef typename boost::mpl::insert_range<
    components_type, 
    typename boost::mpl::begin<components_type>::type,
    boost::mpl::vector<boost::python::object, boost::python::object>
  >::type signature_type;

  // Create a callable python object from inject_constructor.
  return boost::python::make_function(
    detail::inject_constructor<Fn>(name, fn),
    boost::python::default_call_policies(),
    signature_type());
}

egg* make_egg() { return new egg(); }

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(example)
{
  namespace python = boost::python;

  // APPROACH 1: has_back_reference
  python::class_<foo>("Foo", python::init<>());

  // APPROACH 2: custom holder
  python::class_<bar, bar_holder>("Bar", python::init<>());

  // APPROACH 3: custom call policy
  python::class_<spam>("Spam", python::no_init)
    .def("__init__", python::make_constructor(
      &make_spam,
      inject_reference_into_callers_frame<>("last_spam")))
    ;

  // APPROACH 4: decorated constructor
  python::class_<egg>("Egg", python::no_init)
    .def("__init__", make_inject_constructor("last_egg", &make_egg))
    ;
}
```

Interactive usage:

```python
>>> import example
>>> foo = example.Foo()
>>> assert(foo is last_foo)
>>> bar = example.Bar()
>>> assert(bar is last_bar)
>>> spam = example.Spam()
>>> assert(spam is last_spam)
>>> egg = example.Egg()
>>> assert(egg is last_egg)
```

Comment: this is a super-helpful answer that explains boost::python inners well enough to help me solve multiple other problems. Kudos to the author !!

Comment: thank you! I wish the boost python doc was made more clear. I understand both python and cpp. But getting them to work together is a journey.